# Is there a way to send data from Tensorflow to Arduino via Bluetooth?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-nano, bluetooth, python

I am not sure if such a question is accepted here. If not please direct me to a more suitable Exchange.

I am planning a small project involving Machine Learning using TensorFlow and Python, which involves GAIT learning of a quadrupedal robotic system. The robotic system will be controlled by a simple Arduino. This will send data to the 8 servo motors located in the 4 legs of the robot. (2 on each leg) The robot is similar to [this.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MeIh17FivVM)

My question is if there a way to transfer data to and from Tensorflow via Bluetooth to the Arduino.

The Arduino will not be connected serially to my PC, so serial communication is not an option. Bluetooth and Wireless remain, of which, Bluetooth is generally easier.

I have done several projects involving HC-05 modules to transfer data from different systems to an Arduino so that part is not an issue. What I am interested in is if Tensorflow offers this kind of support, or if there is an easier way to do this. Searching online did not yield any results related to what I am after.

Any tips or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: "*What I am interested in is if Tensorflow offers this kind of support, or if there is an easier way to do this.*" That's not an Arduino question.

Comment: Any advice on a better exchange to ask this? I thought that there was quite a possibility that someone from this community would have done something similar.

Comment: [Robotics Stack Exchange](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/) might be a better fit. I can migrate your question there if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is more "Is there a way to send data from Python ?" than "Is there a way to send them from Tensorflow to an Arduino ?" and the Answer is yes.
In Tensorflow your can recover your result in a tensor (which you can easily transform in a Python array) and then send it with Python through whatever support you want to the Arduino.